# How does series parallel combination of LEDs affect the temperature rise?

Tags: led, temperature, parallel, led-driver, series

I was designing the LED light of 200 W with LED combination of 9 series / 8 parallel, each LED is 6V thus total output voltage is 56V. I am using Meanwell xlg 200 W driver. But this resulted in high temp rise and blinking of LED after some time. Does making an LED combination of 8 series / 9 parallel solve the problem without affecting light output?

Comment: If you want to generate less waste heat you need to either use more efficient LEDs or run them at a lower power.  Changing how you wire them will not help with that.

Comment: Aditi, when we were designing LED modules for a display purposes they dissipated about 80 W per unit. (See [here](http://www.infinitefactors.org/misc/images/p1000046_640x480.jpg).) You can see that the front face is an aluminum plate and thick. You can see how the back side is also designed so that it can also be tightly coupled to additional heat sinking. This is NOT a slam-dunk. Heat dissipation is not an afterthought you can paste on, later. Note that this is about half the wattage you are talking about!

Comment: Thank you all. i would like mention that i am using a PDC housing heatsink along with a thermal interfacing marterial of 2.7 w/m-k thermal conductivity

Answer (score 0):

LEDs are sensitive to temperature rise and will fail quickly if allowed to operate outside their design limits. A high power system like you’re building requires cooling to keep that temperature in range. You will need a heatsink and likely forced-air cooling to make that setup work.